# Clear navigation stack on tab change

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am using Ionic 5, and we use tabs for navigation. Example:

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
        <ion-tab-button tab="home">
```

But here is the scenario that makes us problem:

1. User navigates to home tab
2. User clicks My Profile subpage on home screen
3. User clicks another tab
4. User clicks home tab again, and instead of being redirected to home screen he is redirected to My Profile because it is last page in stack

The question is can we somehow clear navigation stack on tab change and have user redirected on root tab screen, which is home in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to this here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/17761

Here is the code:

```
<ion-tabs #tabs>
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab1" (click)="handleTabClick($event)">
        <ion-label>Tab</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
</ion-tabs> 

class TabsPage {
    @ViewChild('tabs') tabs: IonTabs;

    resetStackTabs = ['inbox', 'tasks'];
    handleTabClick = (event: MouseEvent) => {
        const { tab } = event.composedPath().find((element: any) =>
            element.tagName === 'ION-TAB-BUTTON') as EventTarget & { tab: string };
        // without checking resetStackTabs this will work for any tab
        if (this.resetStackTabs.includes(tab) &&
            this.tabs.outlet.canGoBack(1, tab)) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();

            // here we may need pop depth more than one if we handle deeper nav for a tab
            return this.tabs.outlet.pop(1, tab);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

HTML:

> ```
> <ion-tab-button tab="tab1" (click)="clickTab()">
>     <ion-label class="rg-label-menu">You tab name</ion-label>
> </ion-tab-button>
> ```

ts:

> ```
> clickTab() {
>     this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/tab1');
> }
> ```